# Zabbix ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out

Tags: tcp, zabbix, ipsec

We're experiencing some timeouts in TCP communications with certain protocols. Zabbix is one of the affected protocols when using active checks.

A packet capture shows TCP Retransmission and TCP Dup ACK. [Packet capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUblL.jpg) I've been reading about this behaviour and not sure if it's just normal and I don't have to care about.

Traffic between zabbix server and agent travels through an IPSec VPN from US East Coast to Europe. An average latency of 170 ms. No packet loss except first ones when I do a ping flood, but this also seems totally normal.

I can't manage to locate the source problem. We have other locations with the same IPSec VPN configuration with no issues with the Active Checks in Zabbix.

We use Fortinet to establish IPSec VPNs between offices and to Azure VNETs.

Tried to identify asymetric routing or packet loss, etc... nothing strange.

And I don't know what to search for.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your `zabbix_server.log` ? Could be a timeout problem, how many seconds did you set in your `zabbix_server.conf` ?

Comment: Timeout for agent, SNMP device or external check is set to 4 sec. Seems obvious that a Timeout has been reached just as the title says, the agent notifies with: Zabbix ZBX_TCP_READ() timed out.

Comment: This problem did never get solved. We just changed network topology and error was gone.